# Use python generator like syntax while returning back control over to user

Tags: python, generator, yield, stateful

Use python generator like syntax while returning back control over to the user (Create stateful API)

I'm having a sort of API like function where user request to a function and below is my code structure:

```
def api_function(parameters, user: DBUser):
    # I have a global variable with a list (obj_list) of WorkingChildClass
    # assume obj is an object of WorkingChildClass specifically for this user
    # I've very limited user so I'm storing all objects in the list
    return obj.handle_user_input(parameters)
```

Definition for the function that handles user input:
We are storing the next_stage so next time when the user makes the request we'll continue from there instead of starting from the beginning.

```
class WorkingClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def handle_user_input(self, parameters):
        while True:
            is_skill_completed, response = self.next_stage(parameters)
            if is_skill_completed:
                return is_skill_completed, response
            if response:
                return is_skill_completed, response
```

child class, there are many child class for different functionality:

```
class WorkingChildClass(WorkingClass):
    def __init__(self, jarvis_obj, intent_part) -> None:
        self.next_stage = self.stage1

    def stage1(self, parameters):
        # Do some work
        self.next_stage = self.stage2
        return False, response
        # If response is there then it will be returned to user, otherwise we'll continue to stage2
        # first parameter is whether functionality is completed or not, if it returns True then we'll start stage1 again (this will be handled by the main file as it will recreate the obj)
    
    def stage2(self, parameters):
        # someother stuff
        pass
```

What I'm looking for is, instead of writing stage1, stage2, etc function I would like to replace with a generator like (or similar) syntax:

```
class WorkingChildClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def working_function(self, parameters):
        # run stage1
        if need_to_return_to_user:
            yield response
        # run stage2
        # and so on.
        return response
        # when we return that means the we need to restart the working_function from top next time
```

I want something similar syntax which is less mistake-proof than writing stage1, stage2 as a function, and set next_stage variable. And this syntax increases readability.

I don't know if this is possible or not. But if we can do some kind of middle function which stores the state. It could be a middle function like handle_user_input or decorator or class attributes or a combination of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a bit simpler than I was thinking. I just changed the handle_user_input function a little bit.

```
class WorkingClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.generator = self.working_function()
    
    def handle_user_input(self, parameters):
        self.parameters = parameters
        while True:
            print("calling next stage.")
            is_skill_completed, responses = next(self.generator)
            print("next stage completed. is_completed: {}, responses: {}".format(is_skill_completed, responses))
            if is_skill_completed:
                return is_skill_completed, responses
            if responses:
                return is_skill_completed, responses
```

And it works!! Thanks!